# JHipster Initialize db by CSV and after run Elasticsearch returns []

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a problem with searching by Elasticsearch. I use JHipser generator v.3.4.0 and I initialize my H2 database by *.csv files. Next I try search something, Elasticsearch always returns [] unless I add some object manually then I get only this one object. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I used jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer and did POST form swagger-ui and now all objects can be reached by elasticsearch.

*Edit:*

I automatized Elasticsearch Reindexing. It invokes after start application. If you want to do it, follow the steps below.

Steps:

1. Add to your JHipster project Elasticsearch Reindexer from: https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer

2. Reindex elasticsearch on start by adding class:

```
@Component
public class ElasticsearchReindexOnStart implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final ElasticsearchIndexService elasticsearchIndexService;

    @Inject
    public ElasticsearchReindexOnStart(ElasticsearchIndexService elasticsearchIndexService) {
        this.elasticsearchIndexService = elasticsearchIndexService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        elasticsearchIndexService.reindexAll();

    }
}
```

After that, restart your application and now it should works without doing POST from swagger-ui.

Comment: I know, but I must wait one day more until I will be able to do it.

Comment: I have the same issue but still dont know how to fix it. Can you edit your answer and provide more details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have just edited my answer. I think it should help.